# Mysql Rank of more than one column of one user

Tags: php, mysql, rank

How do I go about finding the rank of let's say three stats for one user based on everyone elses stats in one query?

Like

User -> Alan
Level -> 25 (Rank 3)
Wins -> 347 (Rank 1)
Losses -> 2 (Rank 145)

This is what I have

```
function get_rank($what,$user) {
$v = mysql_query("
    SELECT username, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM `users`,
    (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    WHERE id = '".$user."' ORDER BY `".$what."`");
    $a = mysql_fetch_array($v);
        return $v['rank'];
}
```

It never works.

Table Structure

```
Id    Username    level    wins    losses

1     Alan        25        347     2

2     Joe         34        100     4

3     Sam         12        600     12
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us your query then?

Comment: maybe it should be WHERE user = 'Alan' instead ? if  your table looks like what you wrote above

Comment: please post your table structure :)

Comment: I'd like to be able to select the rank of level,wins,losses in just one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT m.name,rank_level,rank_win  ,rank_loss
FROM 
    (SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank_level,name,id FROM users ORDER BY level DESC) m 
    inner join  (SELECT @rankw := @rankw + 1 AS rank_win,name,id 
        FROM users ORDER BY win DESC) w on m.id=w.id 
    inner join  (SELECT @rankl := @rankl + 1 AS rank_loss,name,id 
        FROM users ORDER BY loss DESC) l on m.id=l.id 
     , (SELECT @rank := 0) m2,(SELECT @rankw := 0) w2,(SELECT @rankl := 0) l2
) k
WHERE k.name= 'Alan';
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed3a2/1)